# GetRequest posted argument query string c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, http-post, restful-authentication

How to get request argument of current request posted to a page?

example

External application post the following query string username=abc&password=123 to mypage1.aspx

How does mypage1 get the query string posted into it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Request.Params["username"]
```

btw, posting plain text password in url is dangerous.

Comment: although this works, `Request.QueryString` is more explicit and better performant. `Request.Params` will look through everything (qs, form, cookies, session vars, etc). `Request.QueryString` will only (you guessed it), look in the QS.